# Find a digit at a specific position of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a better approach to find a digit at a position in a number instead of converting it to a string, I feel what I have done doesn't seem best practice and arithmetic!

```
tests = (
    (1, -494848, 4, 8),
    (2, 0, 1, 0),
    (3, 100010, 4, 0),
    (4, 9383.787, 4, 3),
    (5, 1, 1, 1),
)


def run(tests):
    for no, num, place, expect in tests:
        actual = getDigit(num, place)
        if expect != actual:
            print("Test Case", no, "FAIL", actual)
        print("Test Case", no, "PASS", "EXPECT", expect, "ACTUAL", actual)

#Given num, find the number at the position
def getDigit(num, place):
    return int(str(abs(num))[place - 1])


run(tests)
# Test Case 1 PASS EXPECT 8 ACTUAL 8
# Test Case 2 PASS EXPECT 0 ACTUAL 0
# Test Case 3 PASS EXPECT 0 ACTUAL 0
# Test Case 4 PASS EXPECT 3 ACTUAL 3
# Test Case 5 PASS EXPECT 1 ACTUAL 1
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154212/how-to-find-a-position-in-a-integer

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: You might want to look into [black](https://github.com/psf/black) / [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 4):

**When writing tests, try to break things**. It's excellent that you are
writing tests. One purpose of testing is to probe your code -- and the plan
behind the code -- for weaknesses. For example, what should the function do in
the following circumstances? In some of these situations, your code raises an
error (somewhat legitimately in the first example, less so in the second), and
in others it "succeeds" in potentially surprising ways (or maybe not
surprising, depending on your perspective).

```
# Place falls outside the stringified number.
(6, 12, 5, 'string index out of range'),

# Place lands exactly on the decimal point.
(7, 9383.787, 5, "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'"),

# Place lands after the decimal point.
(8, 9383.787, 7, 8),

# Caller supplies a negative place?
(9, 98765, -2, 7),

# Code used for those examples.
def getDigit(num, place):
    try:
        return int(str(abs(num))[place - 1])
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

**Decide on policy before proceeding**. Once your testing has revealed some
edge case weaknesses in the implementation, step back and reconsider your
goals. What is the function's purpose, in what context will it be used, and how
should it respond to erroneous or unexpected inputs? Sometimes the right answer
is to raise an appropriate exception. Sometimes it is to tolerate all inputs
and return `None` whenever the computation cannot proceed. One great
thing about writing software is you get to decide.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly do not want to use strings, this could be done mathematically by determining the number of digits in the integer, which can be done with a simple while loop and counter, dividing the original number by 10 until it is = 0.

Using this length, a series of operations `(num // (10 ** pos)) % 10` is done to isolate a the value. Note you will have to subtract the position you are searching for from the length of the number as these operations will start from the end.

Consider the example below. This code does not work with decimal numbers so you will need to adjust accordingly.

```py
def get_num(num, length, pos):
    pos = length - pos
    return (num // (10 ** pos)) % 10


def get_len(num):
    length = 0
    while num > 0:
        num //= 10
        length += 1
    return length


def main():
    num = 87
    pos = 1
    length = get_len(num)
    if pos > length or pos < 1:
        print("No Number Exists At This Position")
    else:
        number_at_position = get_num(num, length, pos)
        print(number_at_position)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```